# tailwind not working with angular project

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I was working on project where we added the tailwind after designing the structure of our project. One of my collaborator applied the tailwind to his branch and created the pull request. I merge the pull request and then I took the pull from the main into my branch. I ran 'npm install' and then 'ng serve' but to my surprise there was no designing I can see. I checked my collaborator code and match with mine everything was same and has to be as I pull his code.

The designing is perfectly working fine on his end but not mine and its very confusing as nothing related to the project structure and code has changed.

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,ts}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "groveify-bonding-through-rhythms",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

artist.component.html

```
<div class="p-8">
  <h2 class="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Search for Artist</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" #userForm="ngForm" class="mb-6">
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label for="name" class="block font-medium">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" required
             class="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded px-3 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid"
            class="px-6 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded disabled:bg-gray-300 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>

  <div *ngFor="let artist of artists" class="mb-8">
    <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold">{{ artist.name }}</h3>
    <p>Album Type: {{ artist.album_type }}</p>
    <p>Release Date: {{ artist.release_date }}</p>
    <p>Total Tracks: {{ artist.total_tracks }}</p>
    <p>Available Countries: {{ artist.available_markets.length }}</p>
    <img [src]="artist.images[2].url" alt="Album Cover" class="mt-2">
    <br>
    <a [href]="artist.external_urls.spotify" target="_blank"
       class="text-blue-500 hover:underline focus:outline-none">Open on Spotify</a>
    <hr class="my-4 border-t border-gray-300">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried so many ways to solve this but nothing was concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Tailwind directives to your styles.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities
```